# Laravel Package Development - How To Public Path Access in URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-api, laravel-package

In Laravel pacakage development, the `asset()` function is not working. How can I properly use it? I also need to get the URL path of the public folder.

Comment: Probably, assets should be published first? Try it out

Comment: You can try to use `public_path()`

Comment: what is "not working" about the `asset` function?

Answer (score 0):

Go .env File

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Using Config Path

```
return config('app.url').'/images/avatar-male.png';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
url('/');
```

or

use laravel helper function:

```
Generate an asset path for the application

if (! function_exists('asset')) {
/**
 * Generate an asset path for the application.
 */
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
}
```

}